# Get <input> id/value from inside a datatables table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I imagine this question is trivially easy, but I've Googled around a bunch and haven't found anything that answers my question.

Basically, I have a datatables table, each row contains a button with an id unique to that row, and several combo boxes whose values the user must select, and some other information When the uses clicks the "save" button, I would like to be able to loop through the table, accessing the ID of the button on each row, along with the selected values from the combo boxes.

Here's the JS I have right now. (The button is in the first column, and I'm trying to view its ID)

```
var allRows = $("#tblSelectedOptions").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
for(var i=0; i < allRows.length; i++)
{
   console.log($(allRows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").attr('id')));
}
```

When I run this page, [undefined] is logged to the console.

What am I doing wrong? How could I get the ID of that button, and the value of the combo boxes in other columns?

Comment: The variable is named `allRows`, not `rows` ?

Comment: `$.each($("#tblSelectedOptions").dataTable().fnGetNodes(), function () {
    console.log( $(this).find('td:first').prop('id') );
});`

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. The rows variable was consistent, I decided to change it to "allRows" after I copied here, and I forgot to change that one.

Comment: $.each($("#tblSelectedOptions").dataTable().fnGetNodes(), function () { console.log( $(this).find('td:first').prop('id') ); });

Logs an empty string.

Comment: @KevinDustie You are trying to find the `id` of the first `td` using that code, I imagine you are trying to find the id of the `input[type=submit]` or button. Post up a HTML sample of the row markup

Comment: @jammykam Oh awesome! Yeah, no kidding. I changed it to console.log($(allRows[i]).find("input[type=button]").prop('id')));
And it worked!
I got the value of the combo boxes with
$(allRows[i]).find('#comboYear').val());

Thanks!!

Comment: Great, glad it worked. I would change the `#comboYear` to use a `class` instead, `id`s [should be unique](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id) and since you are using a repeater for sure the id is repeated. Not an issue in this case, but can/will cause issues in other instances